# System date capturing in to data base

Tags: mysql

i create a registration form in my jsp project.mysql be the database.i want to insert system date automatically in datebase in the registration time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) of mysql. This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "date_created" field in a table, defined as

```
date_created timestamp not null default current_timestamp
```

When you perform an insert on the table ignoring this column, it will automatically be set to the current time of the mysql server.